# On the existence of a superquadratic map $\beta$ in a paper by DiPerna & Lions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading the paper by DiPerna & Lions on Global Weak Solutions of Vlasov-Maxwell Systems (1989).

On the 9th page of the article, the authors say that for a sequence of initial conditions $f^n(0)$ converging in $L^2(\mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R^3)$, extracting sub-sequences if necessary there exists a superquadratic map $\beta$ such that $\beta(f^n(0))$ is uniformly bounded in $L^1(\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3)$. This kind of argument is repeated later on in the article. I am also posting an image of the paragraph in discussion [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SltXA.png).

Can someone explain to me how the existence of this superquadratic $\beta$ is justified?

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice reference for a proof of this statement, but it is in German. If someone is interested in the proof, feel free to contact me.